# Why are there slave girls in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, slavery

From Captain Pike, to Captain Kirk to Captain Archer a span of centuries, we see examples of [green slave girls](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSgG5M6ANn8).
**Why?**

The Federation's own charter says:

> "We the lifeforms of the United Federation of Planets determined to save succeeding generations from the scourge of war, and to reaffirm faith in the **fundamental rights of sentient beings**, in the dignity and worth of all lifeforms, in the equal rights of members of planetary systems large and small, and to establish conditions under which justice and respect for the obligations arising from treaties and other sources of interstellar law can be maintained, and to promote social progress and better standards of living on all worlds..."

So why does the Federation captains (et al. one would assume) tolerate, indeed *partake*, in the enjoyment/subjugation of said slave girls?

---

I don't buy the [*Prime Directive*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_Directive) argument, they all broke it when they deemed it was for the greater good.

Comment: Orion wasn't part of the federation. afaik

Comment: There wasn't even a Federation during Captain Archer's time. And the Orions were antagonists in both ST:ENT and (briefly) ST:DS9.

Comment: In [A Private Little War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Private_Little_War) the planet was neutral, but that didn't stop Captain Kirk.

Comment: As I know it `Federation founding ceremony, 2161 
Founding Species of the Federation 
The four founding species of the Federation: Humans, Vulcans, Andorians, and Tellarites
The Federation was founded in San Francisco, Earth in 2161` Certainly by Cpt Archer's time, he was born in 2112

Comment: When you justify things with "for the greater good", you necessarily end up with Gulag and Great Leap Forward (or, more ontopic, Gellert Grindewald). Perhaps the Federation ended up figuring that out.

Comment: @AthenaWidget the federation came into existence after enterprise and had only been around for 50-100 ish years by TOS.

Comment: While there are many examples of the Federation attempting to police the actions of other polities (Kirk frequently ignored other worlds' sovereignty), it's hardly normal for a polity to do so. Historically only a minority of entities, such as the modern-day USA and the major powers of imperial-age Europe, saw it as both their *right* and *responsibility* to impose their own codes of behaviour on others. Even when such a group does exist, it usually only imposes its views when it has enough political and millitary power to discourage or avoid retribution and objections.

Comment: Depends on how they *became* slaves, doesn't it? A truly free society would not try to prevent individuals from selling themselves into slavery if that's what they want to do.

Comment: Thank you for asking this question.

Comment: The nuances of a culture aren't to be dismissed.  1) The woman (or her family or whoever) may have a real debt (those Orions are pretty aggressive capitalists). This dancing gig may be the fastest way to clear that debt.  or 2) Imagine an Orion being outraged at the slaves in orange jumpsuits under guard, clearing trash from beside the road.  Maybe the woman is doing her stint of community service.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In "The Cage" one of the men watching the Orion dancer with Captain Pike marveled that Orion women actually wanted to be taken advantage of.  According to [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Orion) this was because Orion women were [Sirens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siren_(mythology)) rather than slaves, luring unwary males into a life of subjugation via potent pheromones.  So the women were not in fact slaves, and the behavior of men around them was the direct result of their hindbrains being tickled by Orion sex hormones.

As for why Starfleet officers would partake of the sexual bounty, consider that these people seemed to live in sexually liberated times.  In the TNG era we had the pleasure planet Risa, where the inhabitants seemed happy to give pleasure to visitors as part of their tourism industry.  There was the civilization in the TNG episode "Justice" that "made love at the drop of a hat."  On DS9 we had Quark and his (to us) depraved holosuite programs, offered alongside the other traditional vices of strong drink and gambling.  It wasn't unreasonable that an officer faced with an amorous green dancing girl might believe that she was happy with her life until presented with evidence to the contrary.

Comment: Exactly right. And I'd forgotten that Justice episode. Thx!

Comment: It is pre-Federation, but I feel this is well covered in the [Enterprise episode Bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bound_(Star_Trek:_Enterprise)).

Comment: +1 a little late but this is spot on, the impression I got is they are called slave girls because they turn YOU into the slave

Comment: "As for why Starfleet officers would partake of the sexual bounty".   We've got Riker! He makes our Jim look like a Trappist monk

Comment: This is a pretty severe retcon of the Cage with stuff from Enterprise. The Cage scene was pure 1960s and earlier Arab slave market pulp magazine motifs...just in space.

Answer (score 25):

Why do human rights abuses exist in real life? I mean, can't the Western European nations just invade every country where human rights abuses occur and vanquish all human rights abuses?

Sure, it's possible militarily, but as we can see with the current spread of terrorism and the hundreds of thousands of civilian casualties and millions of civilians displaced due to war, it's not exactly a desirable option from a human rights perspective.

Also, Pike's encounter with Orion slave girls was in a forced telepathic "fantasy"—one which he was clearly disturbed by—meaning, there was no actual Orion slave girl.

Similarly, Archer did not "partake" in slavery. If you actually watch that episode, he repeatedly tries to break the slave mentality of his guests.

Likewise, Kirk was a captive of the escaped prisoners, which happened to include an Orion woman. In the episode, she manipulates and seduces him (after he'd been tortured using the rehabilitation chair) and then tries to kill him. He was hardly exploiting the Orion woman.

Comment: The first two paragraphs of this answer are pretty much a rant and don't add anything to the last three paragraphs which are a solid, well thought-out answer

Comment: A key part of the question is why human rights abuses exist in the galaxy if the Federation values human rights, as stated in its charter. I used a very current real-life example of why it's impractical for the Federation to govern the entire galaxy. Just because you don't share my view doesn't make it a rant.

Comment: Actually your (political) views mirror mine quite closely. That doesn't make it any less ranty, I'm afraid. I suspect the problem is that you're trying to have your cake and eat it, to dispute the question as well as answering the question.

Comment: @Richard This is the gist of the question I'm trying to answer: "So why does the [sic.] Federation captains (et al. one would assume) tolerate, indeed partake, in the enjoyment/subjugation of said slave girls?" The second half of my answer disputes that Starfleet captains "partake" in the slavery. The first half of my answer explains why they _must_ "tolerate" such abuses in the galaxy outside of the Federation. If you can suggest an alternative wording of my answer that is less objectionable, please submit an edit.

Comment: I'll have a think about it. I can see some room for improvement but I'd want to give it proper attention

Comment: Still seems preachy

Answer (score 7):

**Watch it to the very end.** In the end the "alpha male" captain admitted that he is a slave to the females. The females actually are were fully in charge because the males cannot resist their pheromones. Calling the females "slaves" was just a ploy so they could use their wiles to control the human males.
This episode portrayed an exaggerated version of human culture where the males appear to be in charge but really they are slaves to the females.

Answer (score 0):

An important point not mentioned by others: The Orions were *not part of the Federation*, so the Federation had no legal basis for eradicating their slavery system.  And any other intervention would be an act of war - not something the Federation would like to get into.

Comment: This was already mentioned in some comments, yet not in an answer.